# React Native Error: Build input file cannot be found : /node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/react/renderer/components/rncore/States.cpp

Tags: ios, react-native

I am working on RN to build from Xcode 14.1 but it throws below error:

> error: Build input file cannot be found:
> '/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/react/renderer/components/rncore/States.cpp'.
> Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or
> custom build rule which produces it? (in target 'React-Fabric' from
> project 'Pods').

**Using**:
"react-native": "0.72.3",
"react": "^18.2.0"

**Note**:
NewArchitecture is enabled in RN project. When I execute `pod install` then build is successful but in case of `bundle install && RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED=1 bundle exec pod install`. It is throwing above error.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I just had this issue now...

Comment: This was bcz of Jenkins. So, modifying in Jenkins ruby file is workaround for me.

Comment: I also got the same issue. but in my case I didn't use Jenkins

Comment: Any fix for this? I'm facing a similar issue connected to `Fabric`: `...RCTThirdPartyFabricComponentsProvider.mm'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it? (in target 'React-RCTFabric' from project 'Pods')`

Comment: @RameezHussain Try clearing your cache like this and installing POD : 

`watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf node_modules && yarn cache clean && yarn install && cd ios && pod install && cd ..`

Answer (score 2):

What works for me:

```bash
npx expo install --fix
cd iOS
pod install
```